# 2 input dual inverter using only one not gate

Tags: logic, circuit

How do I make a 2 input dual inverter using ***only one not gate*** along with any number of and, or, xor gates?

[2 input dual inverter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQk0b.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Using this [Truth Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzgPX.png), you can do:

```
!A = ((A^B)&B) | !(A&B)
!B = ((A^B)&A) | !(A&B)
```

where `!` is NOT,  `|` is OR, `&` is AND, and `^` is XOR.

See this hand-drawn [Circuit Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxsef.jpg) for an implementation. I am sure there exist other possible solutions, but this one seems to work.